# Finding multiple words and print next line using Python

Tags: python

I have huge text file.  It looks as follows

```
> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
 257000

> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>
n/a

> <ITC: Delta_G0 kJ/mole 1>
n/a

> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
5000

> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>
1000

.....
```

Now i want to create python script to find words like (`> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>`, `> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>`) and print next line to each word in tab delimited format as follows

```
> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>     > <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>
257000                       n/a
5000                         1000
....
```

I tried following code

```
infile = path of the file
lines = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
searchtxt = "> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>", "> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>"
for i, line in enumerate(lines): 
     if searchtxt in line and i+1 < len(lines):
         print lines[i+1]
```

But it doesnt work can any body suggest some code...to acheive it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't you conclude anything from the error message ? : **if searchtxt in line and i+1 < len(lines):** and **TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple**

Comment: To improve your code: **if any(el in line for el in searchtxt) and i+1 < len(lines):** . But it still doesn't react on **> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>** . A good code needs to be more sophisticated

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '''Enzymologic: Ki nM 1

257000

Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1

n/a

ITC: Delta_G0 kJ/mole 1

n/a

Enzymologic: Ki nM 1

5000

Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1

1000'''
from collections import defaultdict

lines = [x for x in s.splitlines() if x]
keys = lines[::2]
values = lines[1::2]
result = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    result[key].append(value)
print dict(result)

>>> {'ITC: Delta_G0 kJ/mole 1': ['n/a'], 'Enzymologic: Ki nM 1': ['257000', '5000'], 'Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1': ['n/a', '1000']}
```

Then format output as you like.

Comment: You replaced **> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>** with **> <Enzymologic: EC50 nM 1>** in the text. But your code is unsufficient relatively to the real goal expressed by sainitin

Comment: @eyquem Question was edited several times, I used the text I saw at the moment I answered.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know. That doesn't surprise me: there's a problem with this question, which is not only IN the question

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes from the fact that you do `if searchtxt in line` instead of doing `if pattern in line` for each `pattern` in your `searchtxt`. Here is what I'd do:

```
>>> path = 'D:\\temp\\Test.txt'
>>> lines = open(path).readlines()
>>> searchtxt = "Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1", "Enzymologic: Ki nM 1"
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dict_patterns = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    for pattern in searchtxt:
        if pattern in line and i+1 < len(lines):
             dict_patterns[pattern].append(lines[i+1])

>>> dict_patterns
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Enzymologic: Ki nM 1': ['257000\n', '5000\n'],
                            'Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1': ['n/a\n', '1000']})
```

The use of the dict allows to group results by pattern (`defaultdict` is a convenient way not to be forced to initialize your object).

Comment: I don't obtain your result with the text of sainitin, but **defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Enzymologic: Ki nM 1': [' 257000\n', '5000\n'], 'Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1': ['n/a\n']})** that is to say the value '1000' isn't catched.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def search(lines, terms):
    results = [[t] for t in terms]
    lines = iter(lines)
    for l in lines:
        for i,t in enumerate(terms):
            if t in l:
                results[i].append(lines.next().strip())
                break
    return results

def format(results):
    s = []
    rows = list(itertools.izip_longest(*results, fillvalue=""))
    for row in rows:
        s.append("\t".join(row))
        s.append('\n')
    return ''.join(s)
```

And here's how to call the functions:

```
example = """> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
257000

> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>
n/a

> <ITC: Delta_G0 kJ/mole 1>
n/a

> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
5000

> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>
1000"""

def test():
    terms = ["> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>", "> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>"]
    lines = example.split('\n')
    result = search(lines, terms)
    print format(result)
```

```
>>> test()
> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>   > <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
n/a 257000
```

The above example separates each column by a single tab. If you need fancier formatting (as per your example), the format function gets a bit more complicated:

```
import math

def format(results):
    maxcolwidth = [0] * len(results)
    rows = list(itertools.izip_longest(*results, fillvalue=""))
    for row in rows:
        for i,col in enumerate(row):
            w = int(math.ceil(len(col)/8.0))*8
            maxcolwidth[i] = max(maxcolwidth[i], w)

    s = []
    for row in rows:
        for i,col in enumerate(row):
            s += col
            padding = maxcolwidth[i]-len(col)
            tabs = int(math.ceil(padding/8.0))
            s += '\t' * tabs
        s += '\n'

    return ''.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really have too separate problems:

## Parse the file and extract the data from it

```
import itertools

# let's imitate a file
pseudo_file = """
> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
 257000

> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>
n/a

> <ITC: Delta_G0 kJ/mole 1>
n/a

> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
5000

> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>
1000
""".split('\n')

def iterate_on_couple(iterable):
  """
    Iterate on two elements, by two elements
  """
  iterable = iter(iterable)
  for x in iterable:
    yield x, next(iterable)

plain_lines = (l for l in pseudo_file  if l.strip()) # ignore empty lines

results = {}

# store all results in a dictionary
for name, value in iterate_on_couple(plain_lines):
  results.setdefault(name, []).append(value)

# now you got a dictionary with all values linked to a name
print results
```

Now this code make the assumption that your files are not corrupted and that
you have always the structure:

- blank
- name
- value

If not you may need something more robust.

Secondly, this stores all the values in memory, which could be a problem if
your have a lot of values. In that case, you'll need to look at some storage
solution such as the `shelve` module or `sqlite`.

## Save the results into a file

```
import csv

def get(iterable, index, default):
  """
    Return an item from array or default if IndexError
  """
  try:
      return iterable[index]
  except IndexError:
      return default

names = results.keys() # get a list of all names

# now we write our tab separated file using the csv module
out = csv.writer(open('/tmp/test.csv', 'w'), delimiter='\t')

# first the header
out.writerow(names)

# get the size of the longest column
max_size = list(reversed(sorted(len(results[name]) for name in names)))[0]

# then write the lines one by one
for i in xrange(max_size):
    line = [get(results[name], i, "-") for name in names]
    out.writerow(line)
```

Since I'm writting the whole code for you, I deliberatly used some advanced Python idioms so you'll have some food for thought while using it.

Comment: csv.writer(csvfile[, dialect='excel'][, fmtparam]) : **If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.** _http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv_

Comment: I also must write f = open('/tmp/test.csv', 'wb') and 
out = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t') to make the record effective

Comment: **delimiter='\t'** doesn't produce a file formated like sainitin wishes

Comment: Your code doesn't correctly select the data because it doesn't take account of the tuple **searchtxt**

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pseudo_file = """
> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
 257000

> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>
n/a

> <ITC: Delta_G0 kJ/mole 1>
n/a

> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>
5000

> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>
1000"""

searchtxt = "nzymologic: Ki nM 1>", "<Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>"

regx_AAA = re.compile('([^:]+: )([^ \t]+)(.*)')

tu = tuple(regx_AAA.sub('\\1.*?\\2.*?\\3',x) for x in searchtxt)

model = '%%-%ss  %%s\n' % len(searchtxt[0])

regx_BBB = re.compile(('%s[ \t\r\n]+(.+)[ \t\r\n]+'
                       '.+?%s[ \t\r\n]+(.+?)[ \t]*(?=\r?\n|\Z)') % tu)


print 'tu   ==',tu
print 'model==',model
print 'regx_BBB.findall(pseudo_file)==\n',regx_BBB.findall(pseudo_file)



with open('woof.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(model % searchtxt)
    f.writelines(model % x for x in regx_BBB.findall(pseudo_file))
```

result

```
tu   == ('nzymologic: .*?Ki.*? nM 1>', '<Enzymologic: .*?IC50.*? nM 1>')
model== %-20s  %s

regx_BBB.findall(pseudo_file)==
[('257000', 'n/a'), ('5000', '1000')]
```

and content of file 'woof.txt' is:

```
> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>  > <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>
257000                    n/a
5000                      1000
```

To obtain **regx_BBB**, I first compute a tuple **tu** because you want to catch a line **>**  but there is only **"> "** in **searchtxt**

So, the tuple **tu** introduces **.*?** in the strings of **searchtxt** in order that the regex **regx_BBB** is able to catch lines  CONTAINING **IC50** and not only the lines strictly EQUAL to the elements of **searchtxt**

Note that I put strings `"nzymologic: Ki nM 1>"`  and `"<Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>"` in **searchtxt**, other than the ones you utilize, to show that the regexes are build so that the result is obtained yet.

The only condition is that there must be at least ONE character before the **':'** in each of the  strings of **searchtxt**

.

### EDIT 1

I thought that in the file, a line `'> <Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>'` or `'> <Enzymologic: EC50/IC50 nM 1>'` should always follow a line `'> <Enzymologic: Ki nM 1>'`

But after having read the answer of others, I think it is not evident (that's the common problem of questions: they don't give enough information and precisions)

If every line must be catched independantly, the following simpler regex regx_BBB can be used:

```
regx_AAA = re.compile('([^:]+: )([^ \t]+)(.*)')

li = [ regx_AAA.sub('\\1.*?\\2.*?\\3',x) for x in searchtxt]

regx_BBB = re.compile('|'.join(li).join('()') + '[ \t\r\n]+(.+?)[ \t]*(?=\r?\n|\Z)')
```

But the formatting of the recording file will be harder. I am tired to write a new complete code without knowing what is precisely wanted

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to find a string in a line then print the next line is to use itertools islice:

```
    from itertools import islice
    searchtxt = "<Enzymologic: IC50 nM 1>"
    with open ('file.txt','r') as itfile:
            for line in itfile:
                    if searchtxt in line:
                            print line
                            print ''.join(islice(itfile,1)
```